# Restricting the number of digits after decimal in label

Tags: c#

I want the numbers in my label to be like `2.58` instead of `2.5863254689` or any number like this. I need to show 2 numbers after the decimal point.

```
private void ProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    darsad.Visible = true;
    float c;
    size.Text = e.BytesSent.ToString();
    c = float.Parse(size.Text);
    c /= 1024;
    c /= 1024;
    size.Text = c.ToString() + " MB";
}
```

Comment: `c.ToString("F2")`

Comment: Look at [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for ToString overloads.

Comment: Why 2.58 and not 2.59 ?

Comment: Cant you go farther and just do.. c.ToString("F")

Comment: i want to if size.text fewer than 1024k show like 123/25KB like Idm program and when size.text more than 1024k show like 1.25m

Answer (score 3):

You could specify the [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a parameter to the ToString() method.

This will give you two digits after the decimal point but as you can see in the linked article you have quite a lot of options in how you format the numbers.

```
 size.Text = c.ToString("0.00") + " MB";
```

To show the size in KB vs MB depending on value you need to use an if statement.

```
c = float.Parse(size.Text);
c /= 1024;
if(c < 1024) 
{
   size.Text = c.ToString("0.00") + " KB";
}
else
{
   c /= 1024;
   size.Text = c.ToString("0.00") + " MB";
}
```

Comment: i want to if size.text fewer than 1024k show like 123/25KB like Idm program and when size.text more than 1024k show like 1.25m

Comment: problem is when size.text <1024kb show like 125/00  150/00  220/00

Comment: Miky please help me i want to show label like 125/12Kb not 125/00Kb

Comment: @morteza - What do you mean by `125/12Kb`?

Comment: see the picture.this is show in program    http://up98.ir/uploads/138922162342041.jpg  and i like to show like 552.17Kb not 552.00kb

Comment: What was the original value in that case? I really don't understand where the "/" is coming from in your examples..

Comment: i create a program that upload file in server .i just want to when file uploading in server mount of size that be uploaded show the label like 125.12kb uploaded not 125.00kb.i like to tow digit after point showing in lable like 11.89kb

Comment: @morteza - I'm trying to help but you are not answering my question. What was the value of size when you get that? Do you know how to use a debugger to put a break point and examine the values of local variables?

Comment: presuming size be more than 10mb